# speed up imagemagick file conversion to monochrome image

Tags: imagemagick

```
$ file in.jp2
in.jp2: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 3560x4810, components 3
```

I use the following command to convert a .jp2 file to a monochrome pdf file. But it takes 20 seconds to convert a file.

```
convert in.jp2 -threshold 75% -type bilevel -monochrome -compress Zip out.pdf
```

Is there a way to speed up the conversion without losing any resolution and increasing the output file size?

Comment: How big in the image in pixels ?

Comment: 3560x4810 See the output of file shown above.

Comment: Non trivial size, still, about 6s on my Core i5-9400H@2.50GHz, starting with a JPEG (not JP2) of said size, filled with random noise (Gimp's Plasma), from/to an SSD. If you just convert the JP2 to JPEG, how long does it take? This will let you evaluate what is used up by the JP2 decoding.